# IIS giving 503 errors

Tags: iis-7

I am running a Vista machine with IIS7. I believe (not 100% confident) IIS was working fine for me before I installed PHP from php-5.3.5-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.msi from official PHP website. I went ahead with the default install - did not cutomize anything. After the install, http://localhost gives me 503 Service Unavailable error. I have tried diagnosing using following links but can't find anything wrong. Please help me.

http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2006/10/19/Where-did-my-IIS7-server-go_3F00_-Troubleshooting-_2200_service-unavailable_2200_-errors.aspx
http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php

My apppools are running:
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd list apppools
APPPOOL "DefaultAppPool" (MgdVersion:v2.0,MgdMode:Integrated,state:Started)
APPPOOL "Classic .NET AppPool" (MgdVersion:v2.0,MgdMode:Classic,state:Started)

I don't see any errors in either the Application Log or the System Log.

The CGI, ISAPI Extensions, ISAPI Filters are all checked as in http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php

also set following values in php.ini
fastcgi.impersonate = 1
fastcgi.logging = 0
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
cgi.force_redirect = 0

following mapping is set in IIS:
Request path: *.php
Module: FastCgiModule
Executable: C:[Path to PHP installation]\php-cgi.exe
Name: PHP_via_FastCGI

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd list config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi
gives:

`<system.webServer>

  <fastCgi>

    <application fullPath="C:\Program Files\PHP\php-cgi.exe" activityTimeout="60
0" requestTimeout="600" instanceMaxRequests="10000">

      <environmentVariables>

        <environmentVariable name="PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" value="10000" />

        <environmentVariable name="PHPRC" value="C:\Program Files\PHP\" />

      </environmentVariables>

    </application>

  </fastCgi>

</system.webServer>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the solution provided here fixed the problem for me partly. It had nothing to do with PHP. I had added a url reservation sometime earlier when trying to experiment and self-host
some WCF services, and removing that url reservation solved the problem:

http://haacked.com/archive/2007/05/21/the-iis-7-team-rocks.aspx
netsh http show urlacl
The result showed that I had reserved http://+:80/ which takes precedence over all other URLs on port 80.
Reserved URL : http://+:80/
    User: METAVERSE\Phil
       Listen: Yes
       Delegate: No
       SDDL:
D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-1527697538-1582451445-1978546337-1000)
The solution was to run this command:
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:80/
Which removed the reservation.

My php scripts now run, but http://localhost/iisstart.htm is giving me a blank screen. Need to investigate it further...

The blank screen problem was fixed using this post: http://forums.iis.net/p/1158261/1906535.aspx
Control Panel->Programs and Features->Turn Windows features on/off->IIS->WWW Services->Common Http features->Static Content